# Load Balancing Linux Web Services and Change Config Without Restart

Tags: linux, load-balancing

What options are available to load balance web service traffic on Linux with the ability to add or remove servers from the server pool without restarting the load balancer?

This post:

[mod_proxy change without restart](https://serverfault.com/questions/71437/mod-proxy-change-without-restart)

looks like a very promising way to switch between two servers, but I don't know enough about mod_proxy and mod_rewrite to understand how/if I can use an external file to specify the BalancerMember entries for a  section.

Are there other open source load balancers that support reconfiguration without restart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NginX](http://wiki.nginx.org/Main)

- [fast](http://blog.webfaction.com/a-little-holiday-present)
- simple
- reload [configs](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxCommandLine#Loading_a_New_Configuration_Using_Signals) and even [binaries](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxCommandLine#Upgrading_To_a_New_Binary_On_The_Fly) without interruptions

Comment: Awesome!  I especially love the binary reload.

Comment: @Javier: How do I send the HUP signal to the client?  Using /usr/bin/nginx -s HUP?  The -s parameter documentation says allowed values are stop, quit, reopen, reload.  Does "-s reload" send the HUP signal?

Comment: Yes reload sends HUP.  This is working great, thanks.